# Set the maximum value of the y-axis in an Apex chart to a fixed value, and display greater data on the max value line

Tags: angular, apexcharts

I would like to set the maximum value of the y-axis in an Apex chart in angular to a fixed value, and any data points with values greater than that maximum should be displayed at the maximum value line of the y-axis and the greater value should be displayed on the tooltip when I hover on it.
I know it can be done using the "max" property. But when I do this the line exceeds out of the graph.